# Mysql join between three tables query

Tags: mysql

I'm new to Mysql, just started today. I have to use the syntax shown here to add values, so I want to get the director name from the movie with id 289

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`movies` (`id`, `name`) 
VALUES (289,"The movie title");

INSERT INTO `db`.`ddirectos` (`directorsid`, `moviesid`) 
VALUES (1,289);

INSERT INTO `db`.`directors` (`id`, `name`,`last`) 
VALUES (1,"roxy","roxylast");
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear and without your schema, it's difficult to guess at what you want.

Comment: what the question is? how to create SELECT with 2 JOIN?

Comment: Yes,I want to get the director name of movie with id 289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT dir.name 
    FROM directors dir
    INNER JOIN ddirectos ddir ON    dir.id = ddir.directorsid
    INNER JOIN movies mov ON mov.id = ddir.moviesid 
    WHERE mov.id = 289
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.